# Lookup from list column?

Tags: list, lookup-column

Is it possible to look-up anything but single line text values when creating a lookup column?

E.g. I have a list with some general data ind it, one of the columns contains numbers. They should form the basis for a column in another list, but when I try to create the lookup, I can't select the column in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It filters the column list down to just the text fields.  You can probably define a custom field type that may be able to overcome this.

Comment: yep it smells like a custom field type

Comment: I'm surprised more custom fields are not defined.  There are some great possibilities here, particularly with lookups.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an event receiver on the lookup list that copies the numberic values (OnItemAdded, OnItemUpdated) in its string representation into a text field which you can use for your lookup.

Comment: I was looking for a solution thats doable by super users but it doesn't seem plausible in this case