# How to tell if a column is a valid lookup reference?

Tags: 2007, lookup-column

When creating a lookup column in SharePoint 2007 the user interface restricts the available columns to a subset of all columns in the list. How does SharePoint decide which columns are available?

The accepted answer to this question: [Lookup from list column?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1467/lookup-from-list-column) states that it is only text columns, but that answer is only partially correct as the available selections include the non-text field ID (type Counter),  as well as the "Title (linked to item)" option.

Does it add the ID and LinkTitle fields just because it knows they're special?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this translates to SP2007 100%, but from a SP2010 perspective the following columns will show up when creating a new Lookup field:

SPFieldText, SPFieldDateTime, SPFieldNumber, SPFieldType.Counter (i.e. ID), SPFieldComputed (EnabledLookup property has to be True), and SPFieldCalculated (OutputType property has to be SPFieldType.Text).